# Why can't I reflect a list box choice in a text box in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm new to WPF and I'm having some trouble with my existing setup to get the list box selected item to appear in the text box.

The picture here represents the issue. I typed "12 HOUR" in the text box, which then filters the listbox to those items with "12 HOUR" anywhere in the string. But when I click "12 Hour Nasal" in the list box, I now want to reflect that choice back in the text box:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBPHU.png

Here is my XAML for the user control containing the listbox and textbox:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SCM_AllergyRecModule.SearchAndSelectView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel Width="300">
    <TextBox x:Name="Filter" Text="{Binding Path=Filter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ListBox Width ="300" Height="50" x:Name="ListBoxControl"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Allergens}"            
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAllergen}">         
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
namespace SCM_AllergyRecModule
{
public class SearchAndSelectViewModel
{
    private ICollectionView allergens;
    private string selectedAllergen;
    private string filter = "";      

    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.filter.ToUpperInvariant();
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.filter != value)
            {
                this.filter = value;
                this.Allergens.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ContainsFilter(object item)
    {
        var product = item as string;
        if (product == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Filter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (product.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(this.Filter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public SearchAndSelectViewModel()
    {
        var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        cvs.Source = MainWindow.scmAllergens;
        this.allergens = cvs.View;
        this.allergens.Filter = ContainsFilter;
    }

    public ICollectionView Allergens
    {
        get
        {
            return this.allergens;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedAllergen
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedAllergen;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedAllergen != value)
            {
                this.selectedAllergen = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Update 1**

I added the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to my class and have it being raised on SelectedAllergen in the setter. I added an event handler called SearchAndSelectViewModel_PropertyChanged to handle the SelectedAllergen property changing and set it in the constructor.

Now when I click an item in the listbox, I do see it setting the Filter to the SelectedItem and the list filters to that item so nothing else shows. But still, the text box text is not changing? See screenshot below. This is after I typed in "PEAN" in the textbox, then the listbox filtered to two choices, and I chose "PEANUTS (FOOD)", which then refiltered the list box to just show that choice but didn't set the text box to "PEANUTS (FOOD)":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4cGG.jpg

**Updated ViewModel**

```
public class SearchAndSelectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICollectionView allergens;
    private string selectedAllergen;
    private string filter;

    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.filter.ToUpperInvariant();
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.filter != value)
            {
                this.filter = value;
                this.Allergens.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ContainsFilter(object item)
    {
        var product = item as string;
        if (product == null)
        {
            return false;
        }


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Filter))
        {
            return true;
        }


        if (product.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(this.Filter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void SearchAndSelectViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "SelectedAllergen":
                this.Filter = this.SelectedAllergen;
                break;
        }
    }

    public SearchAndSelectViewModel()
    {
        filter = "";
        var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        cvs.Source = MainWindow.scmAllergens;
        this.allergens = cvs.View;
        this.allergens.Filter = ContainsFilter;
        this.PropertyChanged += SearchAndSelectViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    }

    public ICollectionView Allergens
    {
        get
        {
            return this.allergens;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedAllergen
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedAllergen;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedAllergen != value && value != null)
            {
                this.selectedAllergen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAllergen");
            }
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When `SelectedAllergen` gets set, why not just also set your `Filter`? (May need a better mechanism though, as you have some business logic in the setter). Looks like you are also missing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There's nothing for the view to hook into to listen for property values changing.

Comment: Or you can simply listen to selectionchanged event on listbox and set the filter value´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and you can raise it in your property setter.  Since you are also binding your TextBox to the Filter property you need to set the Filter property when your SelectedAllergen changes.

INotifyPropertyChanged example:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...

    private int myProperty = 0;
    public int MyProperty 
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            myProperty = value;

            // Raise the property changed notification
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }


    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and I'm raising the event in my SelectedAllergen setter. How then do I set the Filter property knowing the SelectedAllergen OnPropertyChanged has been raised?

Comment: Any property that you have in your view model should raise the property changed if they are used as a binding in your XAML.  You can Subscribe to the SelectionChanged event and set the Filter property or set the Filter property in your SelectedAllergen setter (I'm not a fan of setting a property from another property's setter, btw).

Comment: Please see my update. I followed your advice but mostly but still something is not clicking.

Comment: call OnPropertyChanged("Filter") in the Filter property setter if you want to reflect the change to the TextBox.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Can you explain quickly why this is making it work?

Comment: I'm at work right now but I'll give you a good link to an explanation.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx